# Assert parameter to stubbed function matches at least 1 value from a list?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

Is there a way to assert that a parameter can be any value from a list?

I know this is the problem line below:

```
someParameter.should.equal('someValue1');
```

That line is correct for the first iteration over array, but wrong on 2nd iteration.

Is there a way to assert something like:

```
someParameter.should.equal('someValue1').or.equal('someValue2');
```

Production code ..

```
function lookupServices(myValuesArray, callback) {
  // var myValuesArray = ['someValue1', 'someValue2']; // sample input
  var failures = [];
  var valuesLookedUp = 0;

  myValuesArray.forEach(function(value) {
    someModule.someMethod(value, function(error) {
      if (error) {
        failures.push(value);
      }

      if (++valuesLookedUp === values.length) {
        callback(failures);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Test code, stubbing the method above ..

```
sandbox.stub(someModule, 'someMethod', function(someParameter, callback) {
  someParameter.should.equal('someValue1');
  callback(null, []);
});
```

Results ..

```
AssertionError: expected 'someValue2' to be 'someValue1'
  + expected - actual

  -someValue2
  +someValue1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
sandbox.stub(someModule, 'someMethod', function(someParameter, callback) {
  (someParameter in ['someValue1', 'someValue2']).should.equal(true);
  callback(null, []);
});
```

Or more precisely:

```
let callCount = 0;
let expectedValues = ['someValue1', 'someValue2'];

sandbox.stub(someModule, 'someMethod', function(someParameter, callback) {
  someParameter.should.equal(expectedValues[callCount++]);
  callback(null, []);
});
```